Is there a way to shut down the Python multiprocessing resource tracker process?
I submitted a question a week ago about persistent processes after terminating the ProcessPoolExecutor, but there have been no replies. I think this might be because not enough people are familiar with how ProcessPoolExecutor is coded, so I thought it would be helpful to ask a more general question to those who use the multiprocessing module.
In the Python documentation, it states that

On POSIX using the spawn or forkserver start methods will also start a resource tracker process which tracks the unlinked named system resources (such as named semaphores or SharedMemory objects) created by processes of the program. When all processes have exited the resource tracker unlinks any remaining tracked object.

However, there is nothing in the documentation stating how to shut down this resource tracker when it is no longer needed. As far as I can tell, the tracker PID is not available to the ProcessPoolExecutor, but I did read somewhere that it might be accessible using a Pool instead. Can anyone confirm if this is true before I refactor my code?

Usually (this is the case of in the answer provided code on my machine) the resource tracker is shut down at the end of the process, so there is no need to shut down in manually. What is the deeper reason for your question? What do you observe on your machine what raises the need to shut it down "manually"?

In the other question that I referred to, I gave a MRE following which the tracker process was still running. The problem is that the persistence of this process prevents a job submitted to a distributed cluster using 'qsub' from completing. If we use the 'fork' method, the resource tracker is not launched and the job completes, but with the 'spawn' method, it hangs in 'running' mode, and needs to be deleted manually.

Hmmm ... does then my answer help you to resolve the issue (it's too complicated for me to reproduce the issue you describe in your other question)? An alternative would be to kill the processes which are quite unique named, so that they can be identified among all other ones.

I will certainly test your answer (and accept it assuming it works). It's what I was looking for.

file a bug report if the thing still runs

Thanks for the suggestion. I have posted an issue on the python/cpython Github page, where I outlined a possible PR that would, I think, fix this, but I haven't had a response yet.
